# Using header files in C

Tags: c, gcc, libraries

I'm having a couple of issues including custom libraries in my program

I have my `main.c` file and a `library.c` (where all the functions are stored) and `library.h` (where all the prototypes are stored).

In `main.c` I'm placing `#include "library.h"` but the functions don't get recognized when I try to compile.

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using GCC to build the file.

**test.c:**

```
#include "library.h"

int main()
{
    int num = 5;
    sum(num);
}
```

**library.c**

```
#include "library.h"


int sum(int num)
{
    return num + 5;
}
```

**library.h**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int num);

#endif
```

Getting error:

> C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\test.o:test.c|| undefined reference to `sum'|

Comment: What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: did you supply the include path using `-I` option during compilation time?

Comment: I have all the files on the same folder, error message is "undefined reference to <insert function name here>" with all of my functions. I didn't make use of the -I parameter, I wasn't aware it existed

Comment: Show the sample files, and compilation statements

Comment: Most of my code is in spanish, would that be an issue?

Comment: According to the description in the question, you are doing everything right. But it doesn't work, so ... you need to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Added the MCVE to the question

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a linker error. What is the **complete** command you're using to **compile**?

Comment: Just using the build/run in codeblocks

Comment: Including just the header file won't link the library automatically. Make lib.c is included with your project, so that both files get compiled *and* linked together.

Comment: @Evert Could I do this without making a project?

Comment: Without a project: see harper's answer. That's pretty much the command line solution.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Humans are not always 100% accurate. Usually GCC is named as the GNU C compiler (omitting "suite"), and indeed GCC compiles the source files altough it does more unless not restricted with command arguments. With the style of question you wouldn't expect a sophisticated problem, so you can assume that the `GCC build` doesn't differentiate a compile commmand from any link command.

Comment: That 's pretty much what I was asking, although you worded it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including the header file is not sufficient. The prototype in the header file just tells the compiler that there should be a function.

You have to actually add the function to the program. That is done when linking. the simplest way would be

```
gcc -o myprog test.c library.c
```

There are more sophisticated option. If you want to add several files actually to a library you can compile them independently and build the archive. Here are some commmands that show the basic idea.

```
gcc -o library.o library.c
gcc -o someother.o someother.c
ar a libmy.a library.o someother.o

gcc -o myprog test.c -l my
```